# Using destruct on pattern match expression with 'convoy pattern'

Tags: coq

For the purpose of this question, suppose I have:

```
Parameter eq_bool : forall (A:Type), A -> A -> bool.

Arguments eq_bool {A} _ _.

Axiom eq_bool_correct : forall (A:Type) (x y:A),
    eq_bool x y = true -> x = y.

Axiom eq_bool_correct' : forall (A:Type) (x y:A),
     x = y -> eq_bool x y = true.
```

I have a function which given two values`x y:A` returns `Some` proof of `x = y` whenever `x = y` and `None` otherwise. This function is implemented with a pattern match on `eq_bool x y` to test for equality, and uses the convoy pattern as a trick to get access within your code to a proof of the equality corresponding to the branch of your match:

```
Definition test (A:Type) (x y:A) : option (x = y) :=
    match eq_bool x y as b return eq_bool x y = b -> option (x = y) with
    | true  => fun p => Some (eq_bool_correct A x y p)
    | false => fun _ => None
    end (eq_refl (eq_bool x y)).
```

I am now attempting to prove a simple result about this function:

```
Theorem basic: forall (A:Type) (x y:A),
    x = y -> test A x y <> None.
Proof.
    intros A x y H. rewrite H. unfold test.

A : Type
x, y : A
H : x = y
============================
(if eq_bool y y as b return (eq_bool y y = b -> option (y = y))
 then fun p : eq_bool y y = true => Some (eq_bool_correct A y y p)
 else fun _ : eq_bool y y = false => None) eq_refl <> None
```

At this point it feels I have to use `destruct` on `eq_bool y y` (possibly keeping equation):

```
destruct (eq_bool y y).

Error: Abstracting over the term "b" leads to a term
fun b0 : bool =>
(if b0 as b1 return (b0 = b1 -> option (y = y))
 then fun p : b0 = true => Some (eq_bool_correct A y y p)
 else fun _ : b0 = false => None) eq_refl <> None
which is ill-typed.
Reason is: Illegal application: 
The term "eq_bool_correct" of type
 "forall (A : Type) (x y : A), eq_bool x y = true -> x = y"
cannot be applied to the terms
 "A" : "Type"
 "y" : "A"
 "y" : "A"
 "p" : "b0 = true"
The 4th term has type "b0 = true" which should be coercible to
 "eq_bool y y = true".
```

I know I have to read CPDT (especially on convoy pattern) but I have a better learning experience with the Software Foundation book (which is suited for beginners): at my current level of skills, I cannot think of anything but `destruct` and was hoping someone could suggest a way to finish this proof.

Comment: @Yves Thank you I have edited my post accordingly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the typical case where careless abstraction makes terms ill-typed. In general, you want to use slightly different principles as to avoid these problems, matching on `sumbool` or `reflect` may provide you with better results.

In this particular case, in order for things to go through you first need to generalize the goal a bit (so it doesn't depend on `eq_refl`, which is a problem when matching as its typing rule is too strict) and then select the proper subterms. I use the ssreflect pattern language as it is far more convenient:

```
(* Do From Coq Require Import ssreflect. *)
Theorem basic (A : Type) (x y : A) (p : x = y) : test x y <> None.
Proof.
rewrite p /test; move: eq_refl; case: {2 3}(eq_dec y y) => //.
by rewrite eq_dec_correct'.
Qed.
```

Indeed, we need to select for matching the occurrences of `eq_dec` in the match and in the right side of the equality proof. You can step the above proof, or you could see the above as building and proving a more general lemma:

```
Theorem basic0 (A : Type) (x : A) b (p : eq_dec x x = b) :
  match b as b1 return eq_dec x x = b1 -> option (x = x) with
  | true  => fun p => Some (eq_dec_correct p)
  | false => fun _ => None
  end p <> None.
Proof. by case: b p; rewrite ?eq_dec_correct'. Qed.

Theorem basic1 (A : Type) (x y : A) (p : x = y) : test x y <> None.
Proof. by rewrite p; apply: basic0. Qed.
```

Note how here, by carefully choosing our parameters, we avoid having to perform tricks with pattern-selection. The key step is to "unlink" the boolean in the match from the `eq_dec` witness present in the "convoy" argument, so we can still correctly type the call to `eq_dec_correct`. The last interesting bit is that we also have to turn `eq_dec x x = eq_dec x x` into `eq_dec x x = b`, thus we need to abstract over the equality proof.

But as I said before, you'll likely want to define even a more general lemma. [Why not use some of the lemmas already present in `eqtype`?]

Comment: Thank you very much for your time. I will try everything out and revert if unclear.

Comment: I haven't got round to using `ssreflect` yet (it will come naturally in my learning curriculum I am sure) , but abstracting over `b` and `eq_refl` with `basic0` works perfectly. Thank you !